# Detect mouse lag programmatically

Tags: linux, windows, mouseevent, mouse, mousemove

Is it possible to detect Mouse Lag using code? Like a windows service / daemon that gets the Timestamp of the MouseMove event and also gets the timestamp of the corresponding Mouse cursor drawing event. And takes difference of the two timestamps to decide whether there was a lag.
Is this possible to do in Windows / Linux ?

Update:
I have the first part of the question is possible in windows using Windows hooks, ie getting the MouseMove event with timestamp. Now, I am looking at the second part - knowing when the Mouse Cursor drawing event occurs.

Comment: AFAIK it's hard to **exactly** know when something is drawn on the screen (without external hardware support). That said lag between mouse movement and painting is pretty small and such measurement won't be accurate and pretty aleatory (because it'll be even less predictable, _standard_ Linux and Windows aren't real-time OSes). In short: **error in your measure will be similar** (or even bigger) **to quantity you're trying to measure** then IMO such measure (to have any value) has to be done with an external hardware (best would be fast video recording board and one USB sniffing device).

Comment: I understand this experiment may not yield the best results, but still I would like to try it out. You said its "hard to exactly know when something is drawn on screen". Can you point me in this direction, ie. how to find out if something is drawn on screen ?

Comment: I suggest to use external hardware for that because measurement won't affect environment. In theory a kernel driver will _know_ when requests has been sent to graphics board but its processing time is unpredictable and monitor delay is pretty high (compared to value you're trying to measure). This is especially true with LCD monitors (where you measure this delay in some milliseconds), _old_ CRTs were better from this point of view.

Comment: Note about hook: Windows isn't real-time. Your application is still regulated by scheduler. Time measurement is still not very accurate (unless you use HPC) and - most of all - values aren't stable. Moreover what you measure is when you get that message, not when user moved mouse (then you don't consider that lag). Finally when you measure that probably cursor has been drawn (because it has its own special management). Even if you solve (somehow) all these problems you still have an unknown variable (as I said in previous comment): graphics card + monitor timing.